# What is the best strategy for acquiring gold in Ultima Online?

Tags: ultima-online

I have been playing [ultima-online](/questions/tagged/ultima-online) for a while now and I'm getting a little short on gold.

I've tried some tactics, but nothing stands out as the obvious best method.  Since it is an old game I think that there should be one or several established methods for most efficiently producing gold.  So, what are the best ways produce gold in UO?

Comment: People... still play UO?

Comment: Problem????????

Comment: Why so much hate on this question ? Yeah I still play this game because it's the only MMO with this unique system that no one else have ever reproduce.

Comment: Warface, you should know better dude. This question is so bad.

Comment: @Ender This question is not a bad one. It's just need some edits. and some "What have you done".

Comment: @Warface its not because the question is about UO, I could care less what RPG you play on your offtime, whatever is fun for you dude. :)   The problem is this is just a bad question. 'What is the best way to farm gold?' Really? In an MMO? Just not a good question.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Some people like the sociopath-simulation of EVE without the graphics, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways and saying this is the "best" would be highly subjective.

But I could say that champion spawns would be the fastest way to make a lot of gold fast. Baraccoon would be the fastest. (Considering you are not raided)

I suggest doing this with 3-6 people.

You get about 250k-500k gold depending on where you make the killing blow on a champion. Try to lure the champion in an open place with minimum water, wall, impassable terrain. This way your champions gold drop will be maximized.

Then use auto looters, horde minions, giant beetles to collect the gold and transfer them to your bank.

This way you can make up to 500k every 20 minutes, depending on your gear. Which means 500 gold/hour if you are 3 people with good gear. Plus you get power scrolls, champion artifacts and some loot. Which may more likely be worth much more than the cash you are getting.